# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Getting Error while invoking adapter procedure

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I am following training module `04_02_HTTP_adapter_-_Communicating_with_HTTP_back-
end_systems`, available on IBM Worklight Getting Started website, and when invoking a procedure it gives me an error:

```
{
    "errors": [
        "Runtime: Http request failed: java.net.UnknownHostException: rss.cnn.com"
    ],
    "info": [
    ],
    "isSuccessful": false,
    "warnings": [
    ]
}
```

Adapter -impl.js

```
function getStories(interest) {
    path = getPath(interest);

var input = {
    method : 'get',
    returnedContentType : 'xml',
    path : path
           };


   return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
              }

      function getStoriesFiltered(interest) {
   path = getPath(interest);

     var input = {
         method : 'get',
         returnedContentType : 'xml',
         path : path,
         transformation : {
        type : 'xslFile',
        xslFile : 'filtered.xsl'
       }
    };

   return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
       }



      function getPath(interest) {
        if (interest == undefined || interest == '') {
    interest = '';
          }else {
    interest = '_' + interest;
         }
           return 'rss/edition' + interest + '.rss';
                   }
```

XML file

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

   <wl:adapter name="RSSReader"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:wl="http://www.worklight.com/integration"
xmlns:http="http://www.worklight.com/integration/http">

<displayName>RSSReader</displayName>
<description>RSSReader</description>
<connectivity>
    <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <domain>rss.cnn.com</domain>
        <port>80</port> 

    </connectionPolicy>
    <loadConstraints maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode="2" />
</connectivity>

<procedure name="getStories"/>

<procedure name="getStoriesFiltered"/>

     </wl:adapter>
```

ahha, finally I got my answer. I did some proxy settings in the XML file and my adapter started working. Here is the Proxy code that one must add if they are using any Proxy.

```
 <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
 <protocol>http</protocol>
 <domain>rss.cnn.com</domain>
 <port>80</port>
 <proxy>
 <protocol>http</protocol>
 <domain>proxy.My_company_name.com</domain>  ----use proxy URL here
 <port>8080</port>
 <authentication>
 <basic/>
 <serverIdentity>
 <username>user</username> --------user is username
 <password>password</password> ------------Proxy Password 
 </serverIdentity>
 </authentication>
 </proxy>
 </connectionPolicy>
```

Comment: edit the question with your adapter -impl.js and xml

Comment: same question was asked by someone here- https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014835720

Comment: Okay, this looks like the default HTTP adapter; can you access rss.cnn.com in your browser? How do you try to invoke the adapter procedure?

Comment: I actually first tried for this"http://engadget.com/rss.xml" but was getting this same error so decided to check with the default HTTP adpater but again got the same error. when I am trying to access rss.cnn.com it's redirecting to "http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/myfeeds". For the rss feed on "http://engadget.com/rss.xml" i am not using any parameters and hence keeping the parameters field blank while when trying with rss.cnn.com I am using  parameter "Africa"

Comment: The default HTTP adapter is working OK for me; it sounds like network access...

Comment: If it's N/W issue then how am I able to open this link "http://engadget.com/rss.xml" on same N/W ? any remedies for such N/W issues??

Comment: BTW.... Idan...what is the URL that you are getting in the browser when your are invoking the procedure for the default HTTP adapter example ??

Comment: http://10.0.0.6:10080/testproject/dev/invoke?adapter=testAdapter&procedure=getStoriesFiltered&parameters=%5B%27africa%27%5D

Comment: Thanks Idan for helping... I got the answer which I have updated in the question. I Hope this will be helpful to others.

Comment: Anil kumar, please put the edit you've made (proxy settings) as an ANSWER to this question. Thanks. Glad you got it working.

Comment: I tried to put it as answer but I can do it after more 4 hours. Weired Rules of this forum !!!.... you can probably add it as answer right now if you want to else I will do it after 4 hours.. :)

Comment: It's your answer so you should take credit for it. :) just don't forget to do this please. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ahha, finally I got my answer. I did some proxy settings in the XML file and my adapter started working. Here is the Proxy code that one must add if they are using any Proxy.

```
 <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
 <protocol>http</protocol>
 <domain>rss.cnn.com</domain>
 <port>80</port>
 <proxy>
 <protocol>http</protocol>
 <domain>proxy.My_company_name.com</domain>  ----use proxy URL here
 <port>8080</port>
 <authentication>
 <basic/>
 <serverIdentity>
 <username>user</username> --------user is username
 <password>password</password> ------------Proxy Password 
 </serverIdentity>
 </authentication>
 </proxy>
 </connectionPolicy>
```